# jsf enter key pressed problem

Tags: jsf

i have a xhtml popup page which has two buttons.The two buttons have actionListener methods in their backing beans.
When the user clicks enter how can i ensure that the first buttons actionListener method gets called.

Comment: j4j allows you to specify a default action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several frameworks provide a tag to allow for this, for example `<s:defaultAction/>` from [Jboss Seam](http://seamframework.org/). It is just adds a piece of javascript to your page that listens for the enter key.

If you aren't using Seam or similar, then add the javascript yourself - for example something [like this](http://snipplr.com/view/3850/check-for-enter-key-using-jquery/)