# Navigation Problem about default enter button in jsp

Tags: html, jsp, jsf, form-submit

I have one jsp which has two dropdown and one texbox and one submit button ok,
when i choose first and second dropdown and press enter it's calling submit button
but when i am using textfied and my cursor is in that textfied and i press enter it's not calling the submit button that means it's not calling action .. can anyone suggest me why it's happening like that...

Thanks
Vinod

Comment: Enter button behavior is different is different browsers? Which browser are you trying this? Please post the jsp code.

Comment: @Aravindra The jsp code is too large... and enter button behavior is different.. it's not related to different browser

Comment: reference link:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205114/default-action-on-jsf-pages-ie-pressing-enter-on-input-fields

Answer (score 3):

Here's [my post about this issue](http://tipsandtricks.nogoodatcoding.com/2007/07/html-single-text-field-submit-caveat.html) and [the relevant section in the spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2) - it's standard behaviour - if there is only 1 text field in a form, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in that field causes the form submission *without* sending the submit button as one of the parameters in the request. When you press enter when the focus is on a `select` element, that element cannot process the keypress so the event bubbles up to the form which then causes a submit as usual.

**Update**
As BalusC has pointed out in the comment below - **the missing submit button parameter is a behaviour specific to Internet Explorer**.

Possible workarounds:

1. Avoid using for the submit button in your server-side logic - *I'd recommend this approach*
2. Add an invisible `<input type="text">` element styled with CSS (`'display: none'`)
3. Use JavaScript to bind a `keypress` listener on the single text field and in case of an <kbd>Enter</kbd>, stop the default action and call your form's submit action. I'd avoid this since it's likely to break your app (like right now) with clients that do not support JavaScript - a simple non-JS form should work with all clients so one of the approaches above might be the way to go.

Comment: and If i have more than one input textfield that time it's submitting only for one textfiemd it's not submitting...

Comment: The absence of the submit button in the request parameter is however a MSIE specific issue. All other browsers sends it along.

Comment: @BalusC you are correct.. thanks For the answer...i will choose second approch ...

Comment: @BalusC Thank you - I wasn't aware of this being specific to IE!

Comment: Never trust MSIE. If you encounter some oddity, it's always good to test it on Gecko based (Firefox) and/or Webkit based (Safari/Chrome) browsers as well. Or just use a *real* browser permanently and use MSIE only for compatibility tests so that you can apply hacks :)

Comment: When I first started dabbling in web-development, I was using IE (been on Firefox ever since!). I never bothered to check this in other browsers since, assuming it was standard. Goes to show how correct your statement is! :)

Comment: @vinod  *"and If i have more than one input textfield that time it's submitting only for one textfiemd it's not submitting..."* That's exactly what I tried to point out - with a single text field, the submission is triggered by the text field itself and MSIE does not think it right to send the submit button parameter. With two text fields, it apparently decides to trigger the form submit as usual which adds the button parameter.